# Simple eth0 config not working

Tags: networking, server, network-manager, ethernet

I am a network guy but I am trying to set up a syslog and snmp server in gns3 using an Ubuntu appliance:

```
Linux Toolbox-1 5.15.0-91-generic #101~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Nov 16 14:22:28 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I am trying to configure the eth0 for network connection to one of the routers in gns3. I edited the `/etc/network/interfaces` file which looks like this:

```
#
# This is a sample network config, please uncomment lines to configure the netwo
rk
#

# Uncomment this line to load custom interface files
# source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# Static config for eth0
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 192.168.13.3
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 192.168.13.1
        up echo nameserver 192.168.0.1 > /etc/resolv.conf

# DHCP config for eth0
#auto eth0
#iface eth0 inet dhcp
#       hostname Toolbox-1
```

After this, I restarted the interface using `ifconfig eth0 down && ifconfig eth0 up`. However eth0 doesn't seem to get the IP address from the file:

```
root@Toolbox-1:/etc/network# ifconfig
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::fc97:d2ff:fe35:b2c9  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether fe:97:d2:35:b2:c9  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 152  bytes 12845 (12.8 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 50  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 23  bytes 1802 (1.8 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Comment: We don't use `/etc/network/interfaces` anymore. We use netplan.io, NetworkManager, or systemd-networkd depending on which one is installed on your system